# What is the use of Byte code in java

Tags: java, class, compiler-construction, bytecode, loader

I am a little bit confused...
I know that classes are loaded by the class loader only when they are needed,that is when we are trying to use static variables or when we are creating instance of that class.Thus if we have for e.g. 3 classes in our program and we are going to use only one,then only that particular class will be loaded and rest are not,but when we run the java compiler,it will create 3 .class files,I know these 3 .class files are byte code files,but then what is this byte code and what is the difference between loading a class and generating bytecode of a class?Where is the use of this byte code?If we are not going to use a particular class,then what is the need of generating a bytecode for that class?

Comment: So it's faster when u want it maybe?

Comment: If you don't want to use a particular class, why would you write it?

Comment: Why is notepad.exe on my system? I am not using it right now

Comment: please format your question properly.

Answer (score 4):

Java is a compiled language. The purpose of compiling into bytecode is to allow the code to run on the JVM on any platform. Platform independence is a feature built into java. 
Furthermore, you don't have to compile all three class files unless they have inter-dependencies. You can specify which specific files to compile in the console javac command. If you are using an IDE, check your settings or exclude the undesired class from the project.

Answer (score 3):

*Loading* a class happens at runtime, when you're preparing to invoke whatever properties the class has.

*Generating* the bytecode of a class happens at compile time.  This allows the code to be run on the virtual machine.

Java is a compiled language, and it runs on top of the Java Virtual Machine.  Compiling bytecode translates whatever higher level code (be it Java, Scala, or Clojure) into [machine-independent instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.1) to be read by the JVM. This is why that your (backend-specific) program will generally run without modification on Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X.

The Java language will compile any classes that have dependencies on each other within the path, so if you have a class but it is not used, chances are it will not be compiled.  There may be tools that override that, so if you find yourself not using a class, then remove the class so that unnecessary bytecode is not generated.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between languages like C++ and java is byte code. C++ binaries(compiled,assembled,linked) will have the machine(op) codes for the OS it got compiled for. In the case of java the byte code is the target for JVM. Byte code will have the opcodes for JVM. JVM in turn will initiate the respective os calls. So bytecode and JVM makes java programs independent of os. 
Reg loading class loading,it happens when the program needs it. This is at runtime. JIT will do the second compilation of class when needed.

Answer (score 0):

When we compile .java we get .class file.
The .class file is called byte code.
The Byte code in Java is nothing but a .class file which is not understandable by humans i.e (00110011). These .class files are generated only after the compilation of .java.
These .class file can be used to run on any platform.